# SQL/Snowflake Coding Question (Insurance Data)

Tags: sql, reference, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Looking to write a SQL Query using insurance data. Example of what I need is below.

We can have a record with the typical format
000000/00/2024/0000

- First 6 digits can be anything (policy reference)
- Next 2 digits is 01, or any other 2 digit combo
- Next 4 digits are a year
- Last 4 digits can be 0000, or any other 4 digit combo.

There's also a facility type column.

For each policy reference, you can have multiple records

i.e - 000000/01/2024/0000 and 000000/01/2024/1111

I need to write a SQL query that checks that the facility type is the SAME for each individual policy reference, even when there's multiple records of each.

The issue I have - Each policy reference can have multiple records, and as a result a policy reference can have records ending in 0000 and anything other than 0000 but we need to check that the facility type is the same between both. Can this be done at all?

Not quite sure how to write the SQL query that can do this check.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Some sample data with expected results that covers more scenarios would help. As written it's not clear why Bunyo's answer doesn't work. It extracts the policy reference from the delimited string, then checks for multiple distinct values of facility type.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work:

```
SELECT LEFT(record_column_name, 6) AS policy_reference_prefix, COUNT(DISTINCT facility_type) AS num_distinct_facility_types
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY LEFT(record_column_name, 6)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT facility_type) > 1;
```

This should return any policy references that have more than one facility type.

The LEFT function is used to get the first six character from your record column (which should be your policy reference). We group by this result so that we can add the distinct facility types within each policy reference number.

Comment: Hi @Bunyo,

Thanks for the response. This is really useful.

There's slightly more to this.

The issue I have - 
Each policy reference can have multiple records, and as a result a policy reference can have records ending in 0000 and anything other than 0000 but we need to check that the facility type is the same between both.

Can this be done at all?

Comment: Please let me know if I am misunderstanding. From what I can tell, this sql will do what you want. It will return any policy numbers that have more than one facility type, which means the facility type is not the same between the entries with that policy reference. It will account for all the different record endings that that policy reference has. Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for.